# Execution context - Creation and Activiation stage

Tags: javascript

I was going through [this article](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) and it was really nice one. I just want some questions which  is currently going through my mind.

```
function foo(i) {
    var a = 'hello';
    var b = function privateB() {

    };
    function c() {

    }
}

foo(22);
```

On calling foo(22), the creation stage looks as follows:

```
fooExecutionContext = {
    variableObject: {
        arguments: {
            0: 22,
            length: 1
        },
        i: 22,
        c: pointer to function c()
        a: undefined,
        b: undefined
    },
    scopeChain: { ... },
    this: { ... }
}
```

1. Why is the length one.
2. What does the scopeChain key contain.
3. What does this refer too. [Does it refer to global context `or` the function context]
4. Can anyone point me to another resource on the same topic and examples which I can try out.

**I am very new to JS side of things. I just want to correct myself and get more clarity from you guys... so that i am not wrong.**

Comment: I stopped reading after #1. Really!?

Comment: @Alexander: I am very new to JS side of things. I just want to correct myself and get more clarity from you guys... so that i am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is called, an `ExecutionContext` is created. This defines a big part in the function's environment.

**1.Why is the length one.**

Now let's see your function, the `arguements` property is created. This object contains a length(ie. that is number of arguements passed to the function)

Now let us look at the below example.

```
function myFun1(a,b){
     function myFunc2(){
         alert("hello");
     }
}

myFun1(10,20);
```

ExecutionContext in the myFun1

```
ExecutionContext: {
      variableObject: {
        arguments: {
           0: '10', 1: '20', 
           length: 2
       }
     }
}
```

**2.What does this refer too. [Does it refer to global context or the function context]**

`this` property is created and it depends on how the function was called.

1. Regular functions** `myFunction(args)` => it would refer to global
   object... i.e window object.
2. Object Method `object.myFunction(args)`=> it would refer to the
   object.
3. Callback for `call() or apply().` The value of this is the first
   argument of `call()/apply().`
4. As constructor `(new myFunction(1,2,3))`. The value of this is an
   empty object with myFunction.prototype as prototype.